# Access values in JavaScript from angular scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

I am building a webapp that has angular on the front-end and c sharp on the back-end.  I am also using leaflet maps to show some data (BTW Leaflet uses JavaScript).  The issue is that I have the data in the scope in angular and I need to access that data from JavaScript which I have not been able so far (countries is simply empty or if I do something like countries.length it says that the it is undefined)

The version of angular I am using is 1.6.1 (this is an old system, I would like to not update the version of angular.
I have tried with:
var countries = $('#idMap').data('values');
var scope = angular.element("#values").scope();
but it simply does not work.

Many thanks !!

Comment: Please could you provides some code of your problem. We don't know if you are on controller, directive, service, ...
scope is available on controler or directive, not in service for example.
Try to get scope from DOM element isn't a good practice

Comment: Make sure you provide enough details for people to be able to reproduce your issue. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).